# Using a DynamicProxy interceptor with dependencies in StructureMap Registry

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap, castle-dynamicproxy

I have the following code:

```
_container = new Container(x => x.AddRegistry<ManagerRegistry>());
```

-

```
public class ManagerRegistry : Registry
{
    public ManagerRegistry()
    {
        var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();

        For<IPersonManager>()
            .EnrichAllWith(t => proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(
                                t, new AuthenticationInterceptor()))
            .Use<PersonManager>();
    }
}
```

-

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Monkey"))
            throw new Exception("Only monkeys allowed!");

        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

It **interceps** the creation of a **dependency in StructureMap**, and **decorates** it **using DynamicProxy**.
Now this works fine, because the **interceptor** has no **dependencies itself**.

But given the following:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public LoggingInterceptor(ILogger logger)
    {
```

**How** would I go about **wiring** that **up in StructureMap**?

Comment: If you came across this question, you might have actually been looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352278/how-do-you-resolve-instances-of-iinterceptionbehavior-from-the-container-when-us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
_container.RegisterInterceptor<IPersonManager, LoggingInterceptor>();
```

-

```
public static class ContainerExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterInterceptor<TDependency, TInterceptor>(this IContainer container)
        where TDependency : class
        where TInterceptor : IInterceptor 
    {
        IInterceptor interceptor = container.GetInstance<TInterceptor>();

        if (interceptor == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("interceptor");

        TypeInterceptor typeInterceptor 
            = new GenericTypeInterceptor<TDependency>(interceptor);

        container.Configure(c => c.RegisterInterceptor(typeInterceptor));
    }
}
```

-

```
public class GenericTypeInterceptor<TDependency> : TypeInterceptor
    where TDependency : class
{
    private readonly IInterceptor _interceptor;
    private readonly ProxyGenerator _proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();

    public GenericTypeInterceptor(IInterceptor interceptor)
    {
        if (interceptor == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("interceptor");

        _interceptor = interceptor;
    }

    public object Process(object target, IContext context)
    {
        return _proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(target as TDependency, _interceptor);
    }

    public bool MatchesType(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(TDependency).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty happy with the result.

Comment: This doesn't work for StructureMap 3+. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815124/typeinterceptor-replacement-for-structuremap-3

Answer (score 0):

I can be completely wrong here, but doesn't this do the trick?

```cs
For<IPersonManager>()
    .EnrichAllWith(t => proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(
        t, _container.GetInstance<AuthenticationInterceptor>()))
    .Use<PersonManager>();
```

Comment: You don't have a reference to the container in the registries. Doing so would violate the RRR pattern as well.

Comment: Ah.. I see. Do you actually need a registry anyway? You don't have to release instances with StructureMap so there is no RRR, just RR :-)